# Breaking up merge sort to wait for user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform a merge sort (I'm open to suggestion of a different sort method) on a user defined list of items. They could be pet names, football teams, or anything else. I want to use merge sort to minimize the number of comparisons the user has to see. In the end, the user gets a ranked list of the items.

The problem I'm having is getting the Javascript to wait until the user hits one of the buttons I'm displaying on the page.

For instance, from the example here: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/02/friday-algorithms-javascript-merge-sort/

on the merge step:

```
if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
    result.push(left.shift());
} else {
    result.push(right.shift());
}
```

I would like to use

```
if(/*user clicked left button*/)
    result.push(left.shift());
} else {
    result.push(right.shift());
}
```

As I understand, the code would have to be broken up, possibly using an iterative version of the merge sort. However, I'm having trouble visualizing how to make that happen.

Comment: Use promises, and possibly `async`/`await`.

Comment: Can you share your full code here or in JS Fiddle